# Accidentally deleted a repository from google source repositories

Tags: google-cloud-source-repos

So, I was doing some cleanup for some repositories on my GCD source repositories, and accidentally I deleted an important repository that -unfortunately- I don't have any clone of

Is there a way to retrieve this back ? Like a recycle bin for source repositories or something ?

I understand that infrastructurely, those things don't get deleted right away.. anyone can help me with that ?

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is no way to restore repositories once they have been deleted. In case the repository was removed from the Console UI and you were using Git it could be you still have a local copy though I can't tell you for sure.

Edit: I have found this [page](https://help.github.com/en/github/administering-a-repository/restoring-a-deleted-repository) of Github's documentation that might be helpful. In few words, if the repository was mirrored from github you might be able to recover it following the steps of the doc.