# Checking disappeared Artifact files in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, artifact, google-artifact-registry

I have two projects in GCP which I have connected from my local machine using **gcloud**. In my project-1, there are already few files of Artifacts are present. Today, when I tried to create a new artifact repository in project-2, it mistakenly got created in project-1 due to which I was not able to see old Artifact repository in project-1. Can anyone please help me in finding the old artifact repository that got replaced.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Once it is overwritten the data is gone.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Ferregina, based on this [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62250897/accidentally-deleted-a-repository-from-google-source-repositories) thread there is no way to restore repositories once they have been deleted or overwritten. Also, according to this [document](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/docker/manage-images#deleting_images),

> Once you have deleted an image, you cannot undo the action.